# How to write a test for an http get request in elm

Tags: elm

I'm trying to check the data received after sending a request and for that I need to write a test to make sure of it.

These are the three functions handling the data.

```
fetchConfigs : Cmd Msg
fetchConfigs =
Http.get
  { url = "http://localhost:8080/api/sso/configs"
    , expect = Http.expectJson GotConfigs responseDecoder
  }


responseDecoder : Decoder Config
responseDecoder =
    map2 Config
        (field "identifier" string)
        (field "ssoType" int)

type Msg
    = GotConfigs (Result Http.Error Config)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/avh4/elm-program-test/latest/ProgramTest. From the package description:

> This module allows you to interact with your program by simulating
> user interactions and external events (like HTTP responses and ports),
> and making assertions about the HTML it renders and the external
> requests it makes.